# What Does Parameter Stand For?

Tags: command-line, gzip

I learn some Ubuntu commands and some commands can take some parameter. I want to ask two questions.

First (more general): Are all parameters which use same abbreviation (like "-N"), used for same task?

Second (more particular): If yes, what does stand for -N parameter and what is its task? If no, what does stand for -N parameter and what is its task for `gzip -N`  command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each command has its own parameters.

You can see what they are by running `man command`.

`man gzip`

```
 -N --name
              When  compressing,  always  save the original file name and time
              stamp; this is the  default.  When  decompressing,  restore  the
              original  file  name  and  time stamp if present. This option is
              useful on systems which have a limit on file name length or when
              the time stamp has been lost after a file transfer.
```

Comment: Does "-N  --name" mean that "-N" and "--name" are same parameter?

Comment: Correct. You can use either way.